# MySQL enable Windows event logging

Tags: mysql, event-log

I have MySQL Server 8.0.21 installed on my Windows 10 machine. I want to enable Windows event logging so that I can see the errors in Windows Event Viewer instead of a txt log file. I am using the documentation from here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-log-configuration.html

```
INSTALL COMPONENT 'file://component_log_sink_syseventlog';
SET GLOBAL log_error_services = 'log_filter_internal; log_sink_syseventlog';
```

However, when I try to execute:

```
mysql> INSTALL COMPONENT 'file://component_log_sink_syseventlog';
```

It gives me the error:

```
ERROR 3536 (HY000): Initialization method provided by component 'mysql:log_sink_syseventlog' failed.
```

- The same from **mysql.exe** in CMD, the same from **MySQL Workbench**. In both cases I connect with the **root** user which has all possible privileges.
- I also installed MySQL Server 8.0.12 on a Windows 7 machine and the same problem.
- MySQL Server is installed as a Windows service.

Did anyone manage to enable logging to event log in Windows for MySQL ? Thank you.

Comment: The INSTALL COMPONENT works here, do you have this file on your system?  C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\component_log_sink_syseventlog.dll  I think it is the component file that is needed.

Comment: Yes, the file **C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\component_log_sink_syseventlog.dll** is in the expected location. It is installed there by default.

Comment: On my system it works 'out-of-the-box' , which reminds me to turn that logging off again, to stop polluting the eventlogs.....

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue. I was able to install other components but component_log_sink_syseventlog kept failing on MySQL 8.0.21. My issue was resolved by updating to 8.0.22 which makes me think it was just broken. I experienced this issue on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016 and updating fixed it on both platforms.